# Outgoing SIP call fails

Tags: python, asterisk, asteriskami

I am trying to initiate a call using Python through the AMI. Code I am using to initiate call:

```
import socket

ami_host = 'localhost'
ami_port = 5038
ami_username = 'user'
ami_password = 'pass'
destination_number = 'dest_nubmber'
caller_id = 'caller_id'


def connect_to_ami():
    ami_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ami_socket.connect((ami_host, ami_port))
    response = ami_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
    print(response)

    ami_socket.send(f'Action: Login\r\nUsername: {ami_username}\r\nSecret: {ami_password}\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
    response = ami_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
    print(response)

    return ami_socket


def make_outgoing_call(destination, caller_id):
    ami_socket.send(f'Action: Originate\r\nChannel: SIP/sipus/{destination}\r\nExten: {destination}\r\nContext: from-internal\r\nCallerID: {caller_id}\r\nAsync: true\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
    response = ami_socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
    print(response)


def close_ami_connection():
    ami_socket.send('Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
    ami_socket.close()


ami_socket = connect_to_ami()
make_outgoing_call(destination_number, caller_id)
close_ami_connection()
```

The python code runs successfully but I am getting this error in the Asterisk logs:

```
WARNING[3907] channel.c: No channel type registered for 'SIP'
```

Comment: There is not a channel driver that can handle a SIP call, as the error says. Perhaps you meant PJSIP.

Comment: Also there are existing libraries to handle the AMI interface, you shouldn't feel the need to invent your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an Asterisk 'error' (or message), meaning that the SIP channel driver its not loaded.

if you have access to Asterisk terminal, try to execute this command

```
localhost*CLI> core show channeltypes
```

and check if you have SIP, just like this image show

[image]

if you don't have SIP on list, check if you have PJSIP, in that case you must change your code to use it, like

```py
ami_socket.send(f'Action: Originate\r\nChannel: PJSIP/sipus/{destination}\r\nExten: {destination}\r\nContext: from-internal\r\nCallerID: {caller_id}\r\nAsync: true\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
```

If none of the SIP driver is loaded, try executing on Asterisk CLI this:

```
localhost*CLI> module load chan_sip.so
```

or

```
localhost*CLI> module load chan_pjsip.so
```

to make it permanent, you need to modify the `/etc/asterisk/modules.conf` file, check this [link](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/basic-pbx/modules.conf) to see options

I prefer to use `chan_sip`, it's more ease to config, but pjsip is the next SIP generation driver